# Run a Vertex AI model locally

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Using the Vertex AI product at GCP training was very easy, I uploaded a data set and it returned a model which is saved in a gcp bucket, I downloaded the files and the tree has these files

```
├── environment.json
├── feature_attributions.yaml
├── final_model_structure.pb
├── instance.yaml
├── predict
│   └── 001
│       ├── assets
│       │   └── PVC_vocab
│       ├── assets.extra
│       │   └── tf_serving_warmup_requests
│       ├── saved_model.pb
│       └── variables
│           ├── variables.data-00000-of-00001
│           └── variables.index
├── prediction_schema.yaml
├── tables_server_metadata.pb
└── transformations.pb
```

I would like to serve this model locally from a dockerized python application, but I don't know enough TF to do this and I am very confused about which `.pb` file is the actual one that has the neural network I need.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: It should be "saved_model.pb"

Comment: I have shown an example with Tensorlfow and Cloud RUn in that article. I could help to package your model. https://medium.com/google-cloud/portable-prediction-with-tensorflow-and-cloud-run-669c1c73ebd1

Comment: thanks! in your dockerfile you mention `COPY exporter /models/tf_models` , what would `exporter` be in my context?

Comment: It's the location of the root directory of model.pd

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you were successful in training a machine learning model using the Vertex AI service from Google Cloud, and that you downloaded the model artefacts from your GCP bucket. The files required to support your model are part of the saved model artefacts.

You must load the stored model into memory and utilize a serving library, such as Tensor Flow Serving, to generate predictions in order to serve your model locally from a dockized Python application.

Using Tensor Flow's SavedModel API, load the stored model into memory as follows:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load
signature = list(model.signatures.keys())[0]
input_tensor_name = model.signatures[signature].inputs.keys()[0]
predict_fn = model.signatures[signature]
input_data = {'your_input_key': your_input_value}
output = predict_fn(**input_data)
```

Replace /path/to/your/saved/model in the preceding code with the path to the directory containing the saved model artefacts.

The saved model.pb file located in the predict/001/ directory contains the real neural network.

A serving library like TensorFlow Serving or TensorFlow Model Server can be used to serve your model over a network once you have loaded the saved model into memory.

I hope this is useful.